# Access characters using load word in MIPS

Tags: assembly, load, mips

I am currently practicing how to use MIPS and I need to access letters of the string using load word only. Since I need to manipulate each character, all I can see is a code using load byte. I was wondering if there is a way to only use load word.

Answer (score 1):

Load a word and [ANDI](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) with 0xFF to get the first char.  Shift by 8 bits and ANDI with 0xFF to get the 2nd char.

(Or ANDI with 0xFF00 and *then* shift by 8 bits, but doing it in the other order means the immediate is always small enough for ANDI).

If MIPS supports unaligned loads, you could also just do word loads at the address of each byte, but then you might go into the next page off the end of a string.  Memory protection happens with page granularity, so aligned loads won't fault if they include at least one byte of data you know you're allowed to read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how does andi work? I am not familiar with it